add route permanently
Ubuntu server is connected via TUN Interface to a VPN Provider.
Fritzbox has a LAN2LAN connection to another fritzbox.
Problem: Device 192.168.178.40 has to connect to server 192.168.178.96.By manual adding:

sudo ip route add 192.168.178.40 via 192.168.0.1

it works until reboot.
How can I make it permanent?
pi@ubuntu2:/etc/netplan$ sudo netplan status
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: none
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: none
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: none
     Online state: online
    DNS Addresses: 8.8.8.8 (stub)
                   8.8.4.4 (stub)
       DNS Search: fritz.box
●  1: lo ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
        Addresses: 127.0.0.1/8
                   ::1/128
           Routes: ::1 metric 256
●  2: ens18 ethernet UP (networkd: ens18)
      MAC Address: bc:24:11:68:ea:aa (Red Hat, Inc.)
        Addresses: 192.168.0.96/24 (dhcp)
                   2003:e4:af2c:2100:be24:11ff:fe68:eaaa/64
                   fe80::be24:11ff:fe68:eaaa/64 (link)
    DNS Addresses: 192.168.0.1
                   2003:e4:af2c:2100:3681:c4ff:feb2:2181
                   fd00::3681:c4ff:feb2:2181
       DNS Search: fritz.box
           Routes: default via 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.0.96 metric 100 (dhcp)
                   192.168.0.0/24 from 192.168.0.96 metric 100 (link)
                   192.168.0.1 from 192.168.0.96 metric 100 (dhcp, link)
                   **192.168.178.40 via 192.168.0.1 (boot)**
                   2003:e4:af2c:2100::/64 metric 100 (ra)
                   2003:e4:af2c:2100::/56 via fe80::3681:c4ff:feb2:2181 metric 1                                                                     00 (ra)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256
                   default via fe80::3681:c4ff:feb2:2181 metric 100 (ra)

●  3: tun0 other UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
        Addresses: xx.xxx.217.6/32
                   fe80::27e:6a10:a643:1642/64 (link)
           Routes: 0.0.0.0/1 via xx.xxx.217.5 (boot)
                   xx.xxx.217.1 via xx.xxx.217.5 (boot)
                   xx.xxx.217.5 from xx.xxx.217.6 (link)
                   128.0.0.0/1 via xx.xxx.217.5 (boot)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256



